# R shiny app greyed out after first run and requires reload

Tags: r, json, shiny

I have a R Shiny App that users can use to look up addresses. However, the app greys out every time after the first search, and the users would have to reload the app in order to use it again. Sometimes it even greys out in the first search (this happens not as frequent as greying out in the second search). Upon checking the log, I am seeing this:

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
72: observeEventHandler [/mnt/app.R#171]
1: shiny::runApp
INFO:__main__:-- Refreshing access token --
INFO:__main__:-- Refreshing access token --
```

Line 171 as mentioned in the warning is in the following code snippet:

```
    response_JSON <- content(response)$result[[1]]
    
    if (response_JSON == "[]"){
        output$noResults <- renderText({'No Results'})
        output$tableTitle <- renderText({'No Results'})
        output$table <- renderTable({})
        output$summary <- renderText({})
        output$download.button <- renderUI({})
    } else{
        output$download.button <- renderUI({
            downloadButton("downloadData","Download Full Results")
        }
```

The app seems to work fine locally and this issue only arises when I deploy it on the server. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I don't know, but this could be due to your empty **renderXXX** calls.

Comment: Error on line 171 `72: observeEventHandler [/mnt/app.R#171]`